# Is there a documented way to secure (with SSL) the localhost cluster for Azure service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

This article shows to how to secure the service fabric cluster in the Azure:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-visualstudio-configure-secure-connections/

But it makes no references as to how to configure developer's machine for the same. I tried to apply the same principles in the above link to see if I can make it work. It always fails to deploy services locally but works like a charm when I publish them to azure's service fabric cluster. If I remove the secure bindings, I can deploy services to local cluster successfully. But this becomes tedious whenever I want to publish the services to the azure's secure cluster.

Does any one have an idea as to how to go about creating a secure service fabric cluster on developer's machine?

Comment: have you seen this site? https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/https-in-service-fabric-web-api

Comment: Yes. It does not explain how the local cluster can be secured with certificate. It talks about getting the cert under local machine store etc but it does not quite go into local cluster. Any other ideas?

Comment: c:\program files\microsoft sdks\service fabric\clustersetup\devclustersetup.ps1 -AsSecureCluster claims to be able to setup a secure dev cluster. I've tried it, and it doesn't work. Can't securely connect after it's created. But maybe it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Service Fabric version 5.5.216.0 and it seems to be working. Run powershell command:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup> .\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -PathToClusterDataRoot "C:\SfDevCluster\Data" -PathToClusterLogRoot "C:\SfDevCluster\Log" -AsSecureCluster
```

Then, open IE to browse "https://localhost:19080/Explorer/". You will see a popup asking you to choose which client certificate to connect. Use the one with name 'ServiceFabricDevClusterCert'. Chrome didn't work for me as it failed directly with no useful warning. Maybe somewhere in chrome I should enable popup window?